# Fancytree Custom json format in source ajax

Tags: ajax, fancytree

I am using fancytree, table extension, I'd like to know is it possible to use a custom json format for ajax request in fancytree.

for example the json format is

```
{"pagination":{'page':1, 'total_page':20},   'node_list':[{'key':1,
'title':'abc'}, {'key':1, 'title':'abc'}] }
```

basically, node_list is fancytree default required json format, but how do I pass node_list to default fancytree for renderColumns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the `postProcess` callback to pick the data source from the response:

```
postProcess: function(event, data) {
    var orgResponse = data.response;
    data.result = orgResponse.node_list;
},
```

See here for more information: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialLoadData#howto-handle-custom-data-formats